# Virtual machine Power state operations using UUID in VCenter API's

Tags: api, vmware, vcenter

I need to do the basic power operations like stop, start, reset, and suspend in virtual machines using the UUID along with the VCenter rest-api. Currently, VCenter has the support to allow passing the Virtual machine name as part of the URL ( Eg: https://VCenter-Hostip/rest/vcenter/vm/VMName/power )

I want to know how to use UUID of the VM instead of the name in the rest url.

Advance thanks for the help.

Regards,
Venkatesh.L

Answer (score 0):

Your example shouldn't work. The API URL is looking for the VM's ID, example: vm-136, not the name.

Unfortunately, the only way to perform VM tasks through the REST API is through the VM's ID.